# check if the text has more than one link

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if the text has more than one link or not
so for that i started with the following code:

```
private static void twoOrMorelinks(String commentstr){
     String urlPattern = "^.*((?:http|https):\\/\\/\\S+){1,}.*((?:http|https):\\/\\/\\S+){1,}.*$";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
```

But the above code is not very professional and I am looking for something as follow:

```
private static void twoOrMorelinks(String commentstr){
     String urlPattern = "^.*((?:http|https):\\/\\/\\S+){2,}.*$";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
```

But this code does not work for instance I expect the code to show match for the following text but it does not:

```
They say 2's company watch live on...? http://www.le testin this code  http://www.lexilogos.com
```

any idea?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If the text has more than one link (2, 3, 4,...) the first pattern should work.

Comment: Could you just do something like (.*?http.*?){2}

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thank u I updated my question, I am looking for sth like the second version that I put

Comment: @dustmouse do you mean this: (.*?http.*?){2,}?

Comment: The question is not to be "professional" (the fanstasm) or not, the goal is to be efficient.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte do u think my first approach is good enough?

Comment: I will suggest a more efficient pattern in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this to count how many links you have:

```
private static int countLinks(String str) {
    int total = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:http|https):\\/\\/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        total++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Then

```
boolean hasMoreThanTwo = countLinks("They say 2's company watch live on...? http://www.le testin this code  http://www.lexilogos.com") >= 2;
```

If you just want to know if you have two or more, just exit after you found two.

Comment: More simple than my approach, even if you need to parse all the string. (but you know the count of links after).

Comment: I suggest adding Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE as a second parameter of Pattern.compile() method in case "http" or "https" had capital letters (eg. `Pattern.compile("(http(s?))://",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the `find` method instead of the `matches` that must check all the string. I rewrite your pattern to limit the amount of backtracking:

```
String urlPattern = "\\bhttps?://[^h]*+(?:(?:\\Bh|h(?!ttps?://))[^h]*)*+https?://";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
// true
} else {
// false
}
```

pattern details:

```
\\b          # word boundary
https?://    # scheme for http or https
[^h]*+       # all that is not an "h"
(?:
    (?:
        \\Bh             # an "h" not preceded by a word boundary
      |                # OR
        h(?!ttps?://)    # an "h" not followed by "ttp://" or "ttps://"
    )
    [^h]*          
)*+
https?://   # an other scheme
```

Comment: Thank your complete answer did u make pattern detail with specific tool?

Comment: @HamedMinaee: indeed, I used my fingers.

Comment: Thanks a lot your post is very helpful